# Facebook sharer.php ignores image

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

have a trouble with sharing site material via facebook's sharer.php

Open window with standart code:

```
url = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=" + encodeURIComponent(title) + "&p[summary]=" + encodeURIComponent(description) + "&p[url]=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&p[images][0]=" + encodeURIComponent(image) + "&nocache=" + randomString(8);
window.open(url, '', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

where p[images][0] has correct image url.

Full URL example: [CLICKCLAC](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=WonderfulTitle&p%5Bsummary%5D=WonderfulSummary&p%5Burl%5D=https://www.agenda.travel&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http://agenda.travel/i/welcome-slide-1.png&nocache=lWttRCIw)

As you can see in Firebug there is right image in DOM tree, but it has "hidden_elem" class hang. Any ideas how to make it work, friends?

Or how to launch my js in iframe window :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might help:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I got your link and image to show with this:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=458358780877780&link=https://www.agenda.travel&picture=http://agenda.travel/i/welcome-slide-1.png&name=Wonderful%20Title&caption=Wonderful%20Caption&description=Wonderful%20description&redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/

You need an app id for this to work, and i hear sharer.php is deprecated and this is the way to go now.

App will give you two parameters for this: APP_ID and REDIRECT_URI will be validated against it.

Comment: This one solves problem, thanks :)
I just wonder why sharer stops working

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible in your case, i would recommend using meta tag (og:image) in head for thumbnail instead of the sharer link attribute

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'm generating share content (including share URL) with javascript and there are no static equivalent for these URLs. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, facebook not show small images, i send bigger images and it works